# Slack Bot: invite a non-bot user when @ mentioning them

Tags: python, slack-api

I'm working on a Slack bot that @-mentions non-bot users into a particular channel. Is it possible to also invite these users to the channel when they are mentioned? (Like when a non-bot user mentions another non-bot user)

I'm using the Python slack client for this, but I suspect what I want to do is at the API level. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The python library don't have the api call wrapped (you could open an issue for that) but the API itself have a way to invite users to a channel, you just need to make a request to [channels.invite](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.invite)